# GraphQL Java annotation - @GraphQLField on nested class

Tags: graphql, graphql-java

I have a class which I would like to use as the query for my GraphQL schema. I am building the GraphQL schema using the [GraphQL Annotations](https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java-annotations) java library.

```
@GraphQL
class A {
  @GraphQLField
  String a;
  @GraphQLField
  String b;
  @GraphQLField
  C c; 
}
```

C is a class coming from another java library.

```
public class C {
  String value;
}
```

Is there a way to build the schema using `class A`, without having to add the `@GraphQLField` annotation on the field `value` in `class C` ?

Comment: I believe you'd have to register a custom mapper for `C`. I'd also suggest you take a look at my project, [GraphQL-SPQR](https://github.com/leangen/graphql-spqr), which will very easily handle what you're trying to achieve.